# Problem with quarkus kafka smallrye consumer multithreading

Tags: multithreading, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, quarkus, smallrye

I set this properties but, quarkus doesn't work correctly.

- smallrye
- kafka have 3 partitions

```yaml
mp:
  messaging:
    incoming:
      event:
        connector: smallrye-kafka
        auto:
          offset:
            reset: earliest
        topic: MY_TOPIC
        group:
          id: my-group
        partitions: 3
```

I see that I have 3 different consumer ids, but the messages are processed sequentially.
I try with all 2.X quarkus version

Anyone can Help me?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hi, have you found what's wrong in your solution?

Comment: hi, i wrote on github 
https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/21306